# "The remote name could not be resolved" error when calling API from server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

On my website I have some calls to an API.

In client side, with AJAX, it works perfectly but from server side (MVC and C#) I'm getting the following error:

> The remote name could not be resolved 'api.website.com'

This is the code that calls the API:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(email);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
var resp = client.UploadString(@"http://api.website.com/functions/email", data);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is DNS correctly configured on the server? Can you run "ping api.website.com" on the server and it resolves ok?

Comment: On the server that the website runs on- no... But on others servers- yes. What should I do about it?

Comment: Well, the problem is not in your code. Fix the server configuration, or have it fixed.

Comment: Can you guide me how to fix it in the server? (IIS I guess)

Comment: The DNS settings are in the network configuration. It has nothing to do with IIS. It's on the OS level.

Comment: So I guess I should leave it to our IT team. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @neuhaus wrote, the problem was due to a DNS setting, once it had been fixed it worked fine.

Comment: Or, in my case, the problem was due proxy setting.